# Get user data from token

Tags: php, symfony, jwt, graphql

I have been creating an API using symfony and Graphql (youshido/graphql-bundle), I want to get user from token inside the API.
I should pass username as parameter in the request, or I can get user from token for all request ?

what is the best solution ? and how I can get token on resolve function ?

```
public function resolve($value, array $args, ResolveInfo $info)
{
    return $this->container->get('resolver.user')->save($args);
}
```

thank you.

Comment: Please link your `security.yml` configuration, all depend of that. If you are under an authenticated route you'll be able to retrieve the user from the token storage (`$this->getUser()` from controllers). You can too get user from the tokenStorage service in all your application.

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: ```$tokenStorage = $this->container->get('security.token_storage');
        $user = $tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
        if($user instanceof User) {
            // The user which is calling you is currently authenticated
        } else {
            // Unfortunately the user IS'NT authenticated :/
        }```

Try that, if you go in the else you have an error of `app/config/security.yml` configuration

Answer (score 0):

If you are developing an API you have to authenticate your user in every request using a Bearer Token. Apis are stateless: they don't store cookie information in your browser (you could, but it's pointless). Instead, you pass a token in the authorization header of each request, and that's your way to authenticate.

You can use the proven [lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle](https://packagist.org/packages/lexik/jwt-authentication-bundle) to implement a json web token auth system. But first make sure you understands what JWTs are and how to use them well.

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to inject TokenStorage in the contructor then get user from it

```
public function __construct(TokenStorage $tokenStorage)
{
    $this->tokenStorage = $tokenStorage;
}
```

to get User from token:

```
 $user = $this->tokenStorage->getToken()->getUser();
```